# How to round a currency value to 2 decimals with access 97

Tags: ms-access

Access 97 has a lot of limitations, but that's the technical constraint to the solution I need.

After rounding values to two decimals and storing them in currency columns, when I make a calculated column from two currency columns, I have on some columns results with more than two decimals. It's very strange because I only do the substraction of a column from another...

Access 97 doesn't have round function, and I can't create currency columns with a limit in decimals with an sql script (my table is a temporary table).

Is there any way to have a valid result in the database ? Or do I have to to calculate this column from the results in the code of my application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format may suit. It always rounds up.

```
  Debug.Print Format(19.955, "#.00")
  'Answer: 19.96
```